# Windows 10, Connected to mapped Drive cannot open files

Tags: networking

Ok, I have a Windows 10 HP Laptop that I have on a network. Connected to network no problems. Mapped the shared drive, again no problem. Opened up shared drive and I can see all files on the mapped shared drive all day long. I go to open an excel spreadsheet, or word document, or pdf file, will not open. But I can take that same file, save it on the local drive and I can open, edit, save..etc. This is driving me insane, cannot figure out what is happening here. Has anyone else had this issue and if so, how do you resolve?

Comment: Exactly which permissions have you been granted on the shared folder?  Can you write a file to the share in question?  Do you have execution permission for that shared folder and its files?

Comment: It's a new computer. The computer name has been changed to access server via workgroup, user profile has not been changed. I can see computer on the network and can access it. Vice Versa. Can see and open all file folders on server, including subfolders. Just cannot open the file itself

Comment: Can save onto mapped drive, but once file is on mapped drive it cannot be opened. Can move file from mapped drive to local, save it on local and can open it, view it, modify it, save it...etc.

Answer (score 2):

After reading articles with other users that had a similar issue, I have found the solution to the issue. All Microsoft Office applications (Word, Excel, Powerpoint, etc.) were opening in protective view.

I went into the applications (each one):

> File>Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Protected View

And made sure none of the boxes were checked. Once I unchecked all the boxes, the programs are starting up without issue.